# colocar a saída de um comando em uma lista python3

Tags: python-3.x

Pesquisei e já tentei fazer de varias formas que isso funcionasse.
executo o mando:

```
ethers = []
ethers1 = os.system("ifconfig|grep eth|cut -c 1-4")
ethers2 = os.system("ifconfig|grep wla|cut -c 1-4") 
ethers3 = os.system("ifconfig|grep ath|cut -c 1-4")
```

queria que a saída desse comando, fizesse parte da minha lista vazia `ethers = []`
tentei com o `append` mas não deu certo, se tiver outra solução sem ser o os.system.

EDIT 1

Bom pessoal, consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
import subprocess, os
p = os.popen('ifconfig | grep eth | cut -c 1-4')
s = p.readline()
p.close()
print("Interface(s) Disponíveis")
print(s)
interface_internet = input(" \n Digite a Interface de Internet: ")
if interface_internet in s:
```

depois do "if" ai farei minhas condições...
espero ajudar alguém com essas informações abraços !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O módulo da std lib `subprocess` pode te ajudar.

```
import subprocess 
comando = "ifconfig|grep docker|cut -c 1-4"
res = subprocess.check_output(comando, shell=True)
```

E no caso, res fica com:

```
print(res)
b'dock\n'
```

Se precisar montar sequências de comando do terminal, existem várias libs que provêm uma api para isso. Recentemente eu ouvi falar da [Sultan](https://sultan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) que parece bem legal e pythonica.

Comment: Guilherme Muito Obrigado pela resposta, mas nesse caso, teria que ter a saída enxuta do comando, pq se trata de listagem de interfaces de redes,
e terá um "input" perguntado a interface que ele quer colocar, coincidente eu conseguir descobrir como fazer, vou editar agora a minha pergunta e colocar a formula. mas MUITO OBRIGADO PELA ATENCAO

Comment: bom, no linux, é só `os.listdir('/sys/class/net/')` .

Comment: E tem também o pacote [netifaces](https://bitbucket.org/al45tair/netifaces) que, junto com as [libs padrão de networking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html) parece ser bem completo para esse tipo de problema

Comment: Valeu Guilherme, Vou estudar sobre o que você falou, obg pelas dicas!